# I am segfaulting with an array that is supposed to be defined. Why?

Tags: segmentation-fault

I need to set up some pipes for a homework assignment as part of a bigger project. I am developing a simple shell. The user types in external commands and my code parses them and runs them.

The issue is that if I try to parse any of the arguments, I get segfaults. My commands are typically:

ls | sort

ls | sort > file.txt

These test the pipelining and I/O redirection.

The issue I'm having is that the array (args) I'm using to populate the pipe arguments keeps segfaulting and I don't know why. Honestly, segfaults keep popping up everywhere whenever I make small changes. Below, the relevant code:

```
char** args;
char** pipe1_args;
int pipe1_args_size;
char** pipe2_args;
int pipe2_args_size;
while (temp_std_command && array_size <= 255) //take args and break them up into an array
    {
        args[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
        strcpy(args[i], temp_std_command);
        temp_std_command = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
        array_size++;
    }
    i++;
    array_size++;
    args[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*255); //terminate array with null
    args[i] = NULL;

else    
    {
        pid_t pid; //Variables for creating new processes and waiting on created processes
        int status;
        pid_t pipe_pid;
        i = 0;
        pid = fork();   //Spawn new process
        if (pid < 0)
            perror("Fork"); //If error creating process, print out error
        else if (pid == 0) //Otherwise if child process, run execlp for external commands
        {   
            i = 0;
            for (i; i < array_size; i++) //checks for i/o redirect
            {
                if(strcmp(args[i], "<") == 0) //input; set read to true and null out unneccesary fields
                {               //terminate loop and copy filename for io
                    printf("read\n");
                    read = 1;
                    args[i] = NULL;
                    strcpy(io_filename, args[i+1]);
                    args[i+1] =NULL;
                    i = 0;
                    for (i; i < (array_size - 1); i++)
                        printf("Args: %s \n",args[i]);
                    i = array_size;
                }               
                else if(strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0) //output; set write to true and null out unneccesary fields
                {               //terminate loop and copy filename for io
                    write = 1;
                    args[i] = NULL;
                    strcpy(io_filename, args[i+1]);
                    args[i+1] =NULL;
                    i = 0;
                    for (i; i < (array_size - 1); i++)
                        printf("Args: %s \n",args[i]);
                    i = array_size;
                }
            }
            if (read == 1) //if read, replace stdin with file
                {
                    int io_file;
                    io_file = open(io_filename, O_RDONLY);
                    if (io_file == -1)
                    {
                        perror("open");
                        return CHILD_ERROR;
                    }
                    if ( dup2( io_file, fileno(stdin)) < 0)
                    {
                        perror ("dup2");
                        return CHILD_ERROR;
                    }
                    fflush(stdout);
                    close(io_file);
                }
            if (write == 1) //if write replace stdout with file
                {
                    int io_file;
                    io_file = open(io_filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
                    if (io_file == -1)
                    {
                        perror("fopen");
                        return CHILD_ERROR;
                    }
                    if ( dup2( io_file, fileno(stdout)) < 0)
                        perror ("dup2");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    close(io_file);
                }
            else
            {}
            i = 0;
            for (i; i <= array_size; i++) //checks for pipes
            {
                if(args[i] != NULL && strcmp(args[i], "|") == 0) //pipe. Copy pipe args to two arrays, set up the pipes and
                {           //call the second pipe function before the first
                    pipe_ = 1;
                    int pipe_index = i;
                    for (j; j < pipe_index; j++)
                    {
                        printf("%d \n",j);
                        pipe1_args[j] = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
                        strcpy(pipe1_args[j],args[i]); //segfault
                        pipe1_args_size++;
                    }
                    j++;
                    pipe1_args_size++;
                    pipe1_args[j]=NULL;
                    j = pipe_index + 1;
                    for (j; j < (array_size - 1); j++)
                    {
                        pipe2_args[j-(pipe_index+1)] = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
                        strcpy(pipe2_args[j-(pipe_index+1)],args[j]); //segfault
                        pipe2_args_size++;
                    }
```

Comment: Seg fault is because you are setting args to NULL after malloc. Why are you mallocing a second time?

Comment: For execvp, I need a null-terminated array of strings for the arguments. The malloc after is to create the space for the null in that array spot

Comment: NULL terminated in the string world means '/0'. When you set args[i] = NULL you are setting the pointer to point to NULL. When you access the data contained in the pointer later you hit the segfault.
Also FYI, I think each string in your args array should be NULL terminated.

Comment: http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/sum01/example1.html

I'm trying to do that but with a dynamic array and string parsing.

Comment: @RamBhat, `execvp` does require a `NULL` to be the last element. However, the OP is allocating memory right before that. This = memory leak. But, it will not cause a segfault.

Comment: -1 Why do you not step debug your program? Whenever you see a segfault, ALWAYS step through your code. Almost always, you will succeed in finding the problem yourself. At each suspicious step, examine relevant variables to see if something goes out of bounds, something is NULL when it should not be, etc. If you could please do that and post your result back here, I will happily remove my down-vote.

Comment: I had to use a debugger to even get to this point to know where the segfault was. I'm going to step through it and see what I get but it's still not clear why it would segfault in the first place.

Comment: @ChavezClemonsJr., So where does it segfault? At that point, what do the relevant variables hold?

Comment: I ended up figuring out what was wrong myself; I can't remember how I fixed it or worked around it since the project was due over 2 years ago. No one who helped me here could provide an actual answer besides insulting my programming method.

Oh, I got an A on this project too and passed the course with an A.

Thanks for nothing, everyone! :)